# Interesting pattern in plot involving prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If we plot $f(n) = \dfrac{n+1}{p_{n+1}} - \dfrac{n}{p_n}, n \in \mathbb{N} $, we get an interesting pattern.

[image]

Questions:

- Why it looks like there's different lines on plot?
- Why they have such shape?
- How those lines can be approximated?
- Why there's like peak at $n \approx 500$?
- Why points in lines become sparcer as they are closer to the bottom?

Comment: Hint: observe prime gaps $p_{n+1}-p_{n}=g_n$.

Comment: Graphing this functions is rather confusing than helpful. The picture gives the (wrong) impression that $f(n)$ is not a function at all since there seem to be several distinct values for the same $n$.

Comment: @Peter When dealing with discrete functions, it is common to plot them like this, and throughout several years of working on Number Theory and Combinatorics, I have never seen anyone get that confusion.

Answer (score 8):

As Vepir suggested in his comment, the curves correspond to consecutive primes with different prime gaps. The one on the top, for example, correspond to pairs of twin primes. That is $$\frac{n+1}{p_{n+1}}-\frac{n}{p_n} = \frac{n+1}{p_{n}+2}-\frac{n}{p_n}$$

The curves can be approximated using the known approximation for the $n$-th prime. For example, we know that $p_n \approx n\,(\log n + \log\log n -1)$.

Here's how it looks that approximation for the curve on the top.

[image]

The curves on the bottom corresponds to pairs of consecutive with larger prime gaps, that naturally occur less frequently.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$f(n)={1\over p_{n+1}}-n\left({1\over p_n}-{1\over p_{n+1}}\right)={1\over p_{n+1}}-{ng_n\over p_np_{n+1}}\approx{1\over n\ln n+g_n}\left(1-{g_n\over\ln n}\right)$$

where $g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$ and we've used the crude asymptotic approximation $p_n\approx n\ln n$. So very roughly, we are looking at the family of curves

$$f_k(x)={1\over x\ln x+2k}\left(1-{2k\over\ln x}\right)$$

with $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.  These curves behave qualitatively much like what the OP has observed; their quantitative disagreement -- the curve with $2k=6$ has a peak value of approximately $.00002$ at $x\approx873$, instead of $.00005$ near $500$ -- is due to the crudeness of the approximation $p_n\approx n\ln n$. Using the better approximation mentioned in jjagmath's answer, $p_n\approx n(\ln n+\ln\ln n-1)$, one gets a curve (for $2k=6$) with a peak of approximately $.00004$ at $x\approx431$, which comes closer to the OP's values.

In answer to the OP's final bullet-point question, the sparsity of the lower lines stems, heuristically, from the fact that large prime gaps (i.e., large values of $2k$) take a while to kick in and remain relatively rare among the first $10{,}000$ primes.